# How to verify that a queue exist on azure in java?

Tags: java, azure, service, servicebus, azure-queues

We have a service that receive the queue name and if the queue exist push data on the queue. 
I'm looking to find a way to check if the queue exist on azure in java. 
So far, using IQueueClient I can onl know if the queue exist when sending data via sendAsync with return a exception. 
I want to found out when the client is created or even before.

The best answer I've found so far is using the NamespaceManager.
in this fashion:

```
Uri uri = ServiceManagementHelper.GetServiceUri();
TokenProvider tokenProvider = ServiceManagementHelper.GetTokenProvider(uri);

NamespaceManager nm = new NamespaceManager(uri, tokenProvider);
if (!nm.QueueExists("TestQueue")) return;
```

source:

http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=12018
https://www.pmichaels.net/2017/06/11/reading-message-azure-service-bus-queue/

However this class seem not to be part of azure-core or azure-servicebus librairy and I can seem to find which lib to add to the project to have access to those class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However this class seem not to be part of azure-core or azure-servicebus librairy and I can seem to find which lib to add to the project to have access to those class.

You mentioned code is related to .net SDK. For Java sdk we could use the following code check if the queue exist. `ManagementClient` seems only available in the [2.0.0-PREVIEW version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus/2.0.0-PREVIEW-5). We also could get the source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/fbfcd1343ca7e64cc6f59076265034160e51f20a/azure-servicebus/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/servicebus/management/ManagementClientAsync.java#L58).

```
String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=SharedAccessKeyName;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxx=";
ConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
ManagementClient client = new ManagementClient(connectionStringBuilder);
boolean isExist = client.queueExists("queueName");
System.out.println(isExist);
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: It's make sense since we use the 1.2.5 version. We decided to assume the queue is always assume known so we won't need to do that check anymore.